# Image Rotation inside WP7 Scrollviewer

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, image-rotation

In an Windows Phone 7 application, I want to apply a 90º rotation to an image when the user clicks a button. I'm doing the following:

```
<Image Height="369" Name="imageView" Stretch="Uniform" Width="394">
   <Image.RenderTransform>
      <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
   </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

At the function:

```
((RotateTransform)imageView.RenderTransform).Angle += 90;
```

So far, so good. The problem appears when I place the image within a scrollviewer.

```
<ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="389" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,78,0,0" Name="scrollViewer" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="409">
   <Image Height="369" Name="imageView" Stretch="Uniform" Width="394">
      <Image.RenderTransform>
         <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
      </Image.RenderTransform>
   </Image>
</ScrollViewer>
```

In this case I get an error - InvalidCastException was unhandled - on this line of code:

```
((RotateTransform)imageView.RenderTransform).Angle += 90;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that imageView.RenderTransform is not a RotateTransform then, but of CompositeTransform instead, so try this instead:

```
((CompositeTransform)imageView.RenderTransform).Rotation += 90;
```

And if you want to specify it as a Composite transform directly in the XAML too, you can do that:

```
<ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="389" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,78,0,0" Name="scrollViewer" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="409">
    <StackPanel>
         <Image Height="369" Name="imageView" Stretch="Uniform" Width="394" Source="/PhoneApp2;component/Images/lumia-920-rainbow.png">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform Rotation="0" CenterX="197" CenterY="184" />
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
    <StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: It works fine! The problem now is that when I scroll the image disappears.. Thanks

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that, but if you place the image inside a StackPanel it seems to work fine, see the updated answer. I also moved the Center of the transform to the middle, otherwise the image sometimes came outside the visible area. Hope that solves your problem.